# c# get the value of button clicked from user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have User Control and named it to `ucMilkshake` and my main form `Form1` each of them has a set of buttons. I put the items button on `ucMilkshake` and Quantity(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) buttons on `Form1` the user needs to click `btnMilkshake` first and `ucMilkshake` will pop up in a `panel` inside `Form1` and there they will see the list of items after they pick 1 of the items they need to choose the quantity of the Item then it will display to `listview` in `Form1`

but I can't get value of button clicked in User Control hoping someone here can help in my problem using `if statement` since I have a set of buttons

heres my code:

User Control

```
public partial class ucMilkshake : UserControl
{
    int clickcount = 0;
    private static ucMilkshake _instance;

    public static ucMilkshake Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new ucMilkshake();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public ucMilkshake()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string MS1
    {
        get
        {
            return button11.Text;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clickcount - 1;
    }

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clickcount = 2;
    }
}`
```

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnMilkshake_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!mainPanel.Controls.Contains(ucMilkshake.Instance))
        {
            mainPanel.Controls.Add(ucMilkshake.Instance);
            ucMilkshake.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            ucMilkshake.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
        else
            ucMilkshake.Instance.BringToFront();
    }

    private void quantityOne_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here i want to use if statement to get the value of clicked button in user control

    private void quantityTwo_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a member variable in your `UserControl`. Instead, create a public property that can be accessed in the `Form`.

```
public partial class ucMilkshake : UserControl
{
    private static ucMilkshake _instance;

    public int ClickCount { get; private set; }

    public static ucMilkshake Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new ucMilkshake();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public ucMilkshake()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string MS1
    {
        get
        {
            return button11.Text;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClickCount -= 1;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClickCount = 2;
    }
}
```

Then in your click event handler of the Form, you can access the value like so:

```
private void quantityOne_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var count = ucMilkshake.Instance.ClickCount;
}
```

Comment: one last favor can you add how to display it to listview

Comment: If my response solved your question, please mark it as 'answered'. Since this question was only for "c# get the value of button clicked from user control", you should make a separate question related to your "new" issue.

Comment: I can't see the output sorry im just a newbie in programming still trying how to display ur answer to listview

Comment: btw I also said to display it to listview its in my post

Comment: i dont' see any listview in your code. what have you tried so far? you will need to first create a listview before you can display data in it.

Comment: `if (count == 1)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.SubItems.Add("1");
                item.SubItems.Add("P118.00");
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }`

Comment: You are sort of on the right track. Have you added a ListView on your form? This is the first step, and easiest to do from the designer.